# Losing control of my keyboard keys daily

Tags: keyboard

Two weeks ago I've lost the control of the down arrow key. After some days I've lost the control of the right arrow key. I was supposing it is some dust there, and I've used a compressed air spray but without any success in fixing the problem. Two days ago I've noticed that the delete key doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know what is happening and what can I do??

Comment: Is this a computer keyboard or a laptop keyboard?

Comment: it is a laptop keyboard. acer travelmate 5730

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyboards are cheap, I would get a new one.  It's likely a fluid of some sort got in there (esp. since all those keys are in generally the same area) and is shorting or blocking connections.

Unless you have a super expensive keyboard, I would just get a new one.

Comment: Not only that, it could simply be wear and tear.

Comment: @sarge - true, but I was thinking since they all started at the same time and the buttons are physically close to each other its more likely to be something inside the keyboard.

Comment: Agreed, just trying to think of other possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Be adventurous and rip off your keys with your fingers then pry out any dust or dirt like a caveman with a bounty of ripe fruit!

Comment: i did that. no improvement :(